# How to add a link to slide elements in MD Slider?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have used the MD Slider module (which is Mega Slider, a paid module) in my websites to create slideshows.

But there is no default option to create a link for each slide.

Is there any way to hyperlink a slide?

Comment: I couldn't find any `MD Slider` module... are you referring to Mega Slider?

Comment: Yes, MD Slider is Mega Slider, its a paid module.

Comment: Apparently there are work arounds. [see this](http://megadrupal.com/comment/671) which is ridiculous for a paid module.

Comment: @NoSssweat - Thanks for the leads. I could not wait longer enough and created my own patch for the same: http://megadrupal.com/comment/13066#comment-13066

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a patch with the changes to convert a slide into hyperlink. Since I cannot upload a file here, I am copy-pasting the contents of my .patch file:

```
From 3f72f263b3673ce27ca4114963b007752b566c2a Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Raj Pawan Gumdal <gumdal@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 6 Aug 2016 11:02:04 +0530
Subject: [PATCH 1/2] Ported changes regarding MD_Slider done for an older
 version

---
 .../templates/front/front_layers_render.tpl.php    | 13 ++++----
 .../templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php     | 35 ++++++++++++++++++++--
 2 files changed, 41 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)

diff --git a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_layers_render.tpl.php b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_layers_render.tpl.php
index a8dd7fc..16c30b4 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_layers_render.tpl.php
+++ b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_layers_render.tpl.php
@@ -11,11 +11,14 @@
 <?php endif;?>
   <div class="<?php print $class; ?>" <?php print $data; ?>>
     <?php if ($layer->type == 'text'): ?>
-        <?php if (isset($link)):?>
-            <a href="<?php print $link;?>"<?php if (isset($layer->link["target"]) && !empty($layer->link["target"])) print " target='{$layer->link["target"]}'";?>><?php print $layer->title;?></a>
-        <?php else:?>
-            <?php print $layer->title;?>
-        <?php endif; ?>
+    <?php /* Raj: Changes to make MD_Slider slide as hyperlink */?>
+       <?php if (strpos($layer->title,'URL:') === false):?>
+           <?php if (isset($link)):?>
+               <a href="<?php print $link;?>"<?php if (isset($layer->link["target"]) && !empty($layer->link["target"])) print " target='{$layer->link["target"]}'";?>><?php print $layer->title;?></a>
+           <?php else:?>
+               <?php print $layer->title;?>
+           <?php endif; ?>
+        <?php endif; ?>        
     <?php elseif ($layer->type == 'image'): ?>
         <?php if (isset($link)):?>
             <a href="<?php print $link;?>"<?php if (isset($layer->link["target"]) && !empty($layer->link["target"])) print " target='{$layer->link["target"]}'";?>>
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
index 8df2c39..5dd71dd 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
+++ b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
@@ -18,10 +18,41 @@
       <div class="md-slider-overlay" style="background: <?php print $slide->settings['background_overlay']; ?>">
       </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
-    <div class="md-objects">
+
+    <?php
+    // Raj: Check if there is a string which starts from "URL:". If so, extract the URL and make this div a hyperlink
+    $hasURL = false;
+    $URLString = '';
+    foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):
+    $layerTitle = $layer["title"];
+    drupal_set_message("Layer object: $layer");
+    drupal_set_message("Layer title: $layerTitle");
+    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/260665
+    if (strpos($layerTitle,'URL:') !== false) {
+       $hasURL = true;
+       $URLString = str_replace('URL:', '', $layerTitle);
+       break;
+    }
+    endforeach;
+    
+    if ($hasURL)
+    {
+       print "<a href=$URLString>";
+    }
+    print "<div class=\"md-objects\">";
+    foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):
+    print theme('front_layers_render', array('index' => $index, 'layer' => $layer));
+    endforeach;
+    print "</div>";
+    if ($hasURL)
+    {
+       print "</a>";
+    }
+    ?>
+<!--     <div class="md-objects"> -->
       <?php foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):?>
         <?php print theme('front_layers_render', array('index' => $index, 'layer' => $layer));?>
       <?php endforeach;?>
-    </div>
+<!--     </div> -->
   </div>
 <?php endif;?>
-- 
2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)


From 74c3d0644fd505729163d4803c9a0f9cb014e679 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Raj Pawan Gumdal <gumdal@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 6 Aug 2016 14:04:39 +0530
Subject: [PATCH 2/2] Finalized the changes to support hyperlinking whole slide

---
 .../templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php     | 30 +++++++++++++---------
 sites/all/themes/IndianSnakes/css/custom.css       |  6 +++++
 2 files changed, 24 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)

diff --git a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
index 5dd71dd..764d46e 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
+++ b/sites/all/modules/md_slider/templates/front/front_slide_render.tpl.php
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@

 <?php if (!isset($slide->settings["disabled"]) || !$slide->settings["disabled"]):?>
   <div class="md-slide-item slide-<?php print $index+1;?>" <?php print $data_properties;?>>
+  
     <div class="md-mainimg" style="<?php print $background_style;?>">
       <?php if (!empty($background_url)):?>
         <img src="<?php print $background_url;?>" alt="<?php print htmlentities($slide->settings["background_image_alt"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>"<?php print $background_style;?> />
@@ -25,34 +26,39 @@
     $URLString = '';
     foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):
     $layerTitle = $layer["title"];
-    drupal_set_message("Layer object: $layer");
-    drupal_set_message("Layer title: $layerTitle");
+//     drupal_set_message("Layer object: $layer");
+//     drupal_set_message("Layer title: $layerTitle");
     // http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/260665
-    if (strpos($layerTitle,'URL:') !== false) {
+    if (strpos($layerTitle,'URL:') === false) {
+    }
+    else {
        $hasURL = true;
-       $URLString = str_replace('URL:', '', $layerTitle);
+       $URLString = str_replace('URL:','',$layerTitle);
        break;
     }
     endforeach;
-    
+//     drupal_set_message("URL: $URLString");
+//     drupal_set_message("Has URL: $hasURL");
+    $outputString = "";
     if ($hasURL)
     {
-       print "<a href=$URLString>";
+       $outputString .= "<a href=$URLString >"; 
     }
-    print "<div class=\"md-objects\">";
+    $outputString .= "<div class=\"md-objects\">";
     foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):
-    print theme('front_layers_render', array('index' => $index, 'layer' => $layer));
+    $outputString .= theme('front_layers_render', array('index' => $index, 'layer' => $layer));
     endforeach;
-    print "</div>";
+    $outputString .= "</div>"; 
     if ($hasURL)
     {
-       print "</a>";
+       $outputString .= "</a>"; 
     }
+    print $outputString;
     ?>
-<!--     <div class="md-objects"> -->
+<!--     <div class="md-objects">
       <?php foreach ($slide->layers as $index => $layer):?>
         <?php print theme('front_layers_render', array('index' => $index, 'layer' => $layer));?>
       <?php endforeach;?>
-<!--     </div> -->
+</div> -->
   </div>
 <?php endif;?>
diff --git a/sites/all/themes/IndianSnakes/css/custom.css b/sites/all/themes/IndianSnakes/css/custom.css
index 3d69b0d..3f0354e 100644
--- a/sites/all/themes/IndianSnakes/css/custom.css
+++ b/sites/all/themes/IndianSnakes/css/custom.css
@@ -27,3 +27,9 @@ display: inline-block;
 width: auto !important;
 height: 300px !important;
 }
+
+/* Reset the hyperlink style to normal inside slides */
+.md-slide-item a {
+    color: inherit;
+    text-decoration: inherit;
+}
\ No newline at end of file
-- 
2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
```

I have defined a new "**URL:**" label protocol for each slide. If a slide has this label defined then the whole slide's div is converted into hyperlink with whatever link is provided after my **URL:** protocol. For example check this:

[image]

The code (patch) is configured such that label with text which begins with `URL:` is never rendered as text but it is used to convert the slide into a hyperlink.

For a live working example check: [http://indiansnakes.org/homepage](http://megadrupal.com/comment/671)

Assumption:
The only limitation of this method is, you should not hyperlink any text or images which are used within this hyperlinked slide coz the anchor tags cannot be nested, apparently.

**Edit**: I thought its best to update the patch details in the MD Slider community as well, here it is: http://megadrupal.com/comment/13066#comment-13066

Also a gist is created with the contents of same patch: https://gist.github.com/gumdal/e580cd80199c871fa52f677538771551